# Is it possible that library made in visual studio can`t linking to mingw g++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, mingw

I made static library in visual studio called MyString. (TEST PURPOSE)

And trying to linking using cmake tool and set the compiler mingw64.

But it seems not working It`s showing me some error called
'skipping incompatible when searching for library'

Is that impossible to linking library that made by another compiler?

Comment: Different compilers mangle names differently.

Comment: For best results, link the libraries that were created with the same compiler as your program.

Comment: @ChrisMM How to set compiler name differently?

Comment: Look at this about name mangling: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#How_different_compilers_mangle_the_same_functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#How_different_compilers_mangle_the_same_functions)

Answer (score 1):

There are many challenges mixing different compilers, like:

- Name mangling (the way symbols are exported), especially when using C++
- Different compilers use different standard libraries, which may cause serious problems. Imagine for example memory allocated with GCC/MinGW `malloc()` being released with MSVC `free()`, which will not work.

With static libraries it is especially hard (e.g. `malloc()` can be linked to the wrong standard library).

With shared libraries there may be possibilities to solve these issues and get it to work, at least when sticking to C. For C++ it may be a lot more challenging.